# Acro package: \printacronyms translation

Tags: languages, babel, acronyms

While using `acro` package, I get the following message:

> Package translations Warning: Translation for `acronym-list-name' in
>   portuguese  unknown. on input line 67.
>
> Package translations Warning: Using fallback translation for
>   `acronym-list-name '.

The problem here is that I am writing a document in Portuguese and no translation is found for that language. How can I provide such translation?

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[portuguese]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{TV}{%
    short = TV,
    long = Televisão
}

\begin{document}

\printacronyms

A \ac{TV} é a caixa mágica que revolucionou o mundo.

\end{document}
```

Comment: The translations have been added to v1.2a. (I also added a section about language support.) Thanks for your contribution :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `\DeclareTranslation{Portuguese}{acronym-list-name}{<correct translation>}` to your preamble:

```
\documentclass[portuguese]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{acro}
\DeclareAcronym{TV}{%
    short = TV,
    long = Televisão
}

% this is what google translate tells me:
\DeclareTranslation{Portuguese}{acronym-list-name}{Siglas}

\begin{document}

\printacronyms

A \ac{TV} é a caixa mágica que revolucionou o mundo.

\end{document}
```

The `acro` package uses the [`translations` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/translations) for the translations and uses other translated strings, too, which you also may want to add for Portuguese:

```
\DeclareTranslation{English}{acronym-page-name}{p.}
\DeclareTranslation{English}{acronym-pages-name}{pp.}
\DeclareTranslation{English}{acronym-next-page}{f.}
\DeclareTranslation{English}{acronym-next-pages}{ff.}
```

If you send me an email (you'll find my address in the `acro` documentation) with the correct translations I'll add them to `acro`.